# Mixing jackson core annotations and jaxb annotations when using jersey

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have a method in a jaxb annotated class that I want to marshall a value if and only if it is marshalling to JSON with jersey 1.16 - which is using jackson 1.9 underneath. I was hoping to use @XmlTransient from jaxb and @JsonProperty from jackson on getting this done in a way like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeClass {  

  // Other XmlElement annotated methods

  @XmlTransient
  @JsonProperty(value="type")
  public String getType(){
      return this.type;
  }

}
```

... but it doesn't seem to marshall at all. No errors are encountered.

Comment: Would you be so kind to give code that 'doesn't marshall'?

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was I was using the natural JSON processors which seems to ignore the JsonProperty annotation, I believe this to be true because I believe Jersey converts to XML and then to JSON when using the natural JSON processor.

The marshalling code is actually hidden, as it's marshalled by the Jersey resource.

Answer (score 0):

1. I needed to switch Jersey to use the POJOMappingFeature, which uses Jackson.
2. I needed to not include XmlTransient, otherwise it seemed like the element was ignored. In some cases I believe getType might still be serialized in the XML, however, I was using propOrder in my actual class, and because XmlElement wasn't declared on getType, this wasn't a problem. For those other cases where it may be a problem, I think you'd need to use something like jsonGetType in order to make sure it's not serialized by default.